# How to get column names back from df.apply call in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Conundrum: I need to use df.apply with a row of data from 
df, but I don't know the names of the return columns at the 
time I call df.apply, and the column names are dependent on 
the row input to df.apply...

There are some other stackoverflow discussions about pd.concat 
and result_type='expand', but they don't see quite right for my purpose.

Please respond with a simple, few lines as possible apply strategy..

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(x):

    # get_dictionary call will return a consistent number of key/values pairs
    # with the keys being consistent each call.
    # e.g. {'key1': [5], 'key2': [5.6]}
    dict_of_vals = get_dictionary(x.name, x.some_other_value)

    # create a Series with the values - ONE row # can't name columns here??
    return pd.Series( list(dict_of_vals.values()) )


# assume df is init with some number of columns/rows,
# see below for example
df = init()

# I need the keys from the my_func call e.g. dict_of_vals.keys()
# for the column names here
df[DONT_KNOW_KEYS_UNTIL_CALL_TO_MY_FUNC] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), axis=1)

# assume initial table from init call above
   numbers colors
0        1    red
1        2  white
2        3   blue

# want solution to look something like this:
   numbers colors  key1  key2
0        1    red     5   5.6
1        2  white     6   7.7
2        3   blue     7   8.8

Again, I won't know the column names and values until the apply 
calls my_func.


example, if
dict_of_vals = {'key1': [5], 'key2': [5.6]}

I get 
  key1   key2
0  [5]  [5.6]
1  [5]  [5.6]
2  [5]  [5.6]

which is missing the original columns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can name the indices of the pandas.Series, they will become the column names in the dataframe created by df.apply.

Then you can join or append the newly created dataframe with your original dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(5), columns=['Numbers'])

   Numbers
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4

def my_func(x):
    number = x['Numbers']
    return pd.Series([number*2, number*3], index=['Times2', 'Times3'])

df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), axis=1)

   Times2  Times3
0       0       0
1       2       3
2       4       6
3       6       9
4       8      12

df_final = df1.join(df2)

   Numbers  Times2  Times3
0        0       0       0
1        1       2       3
2        2       4       6
3        3       6       9
4        4       8      12
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Pandas' append function.

```
df.append(df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), axis=1))
```

This way it is possible to append a DataFrame of unknown columns and get a combined DataFrame of they original and new columns

Answer (score 0):

You can easily grab the column names inside the df.apply function with `list(row.index)`.

Then easily create a dictionary with key value by using the below:

```
def apply_extraction(row):
  column_names = list(row.index) 
  dic = {name: row[name] for name in column_names}
  return dic
```